# Casting NULL to void in C++

Tags: c, pointers, null, void

I ran across a puzzling notation:

```
if(ptr != (void)(NULL)) {
    //some action
}
```

So it expanded to

```
if(ptr != (void)((void *)0)) {
    //some action
}
```

which seems at least strange.
Is there really any rationale behind that or is it simply pointless, or even wrong? It compiled fine, though (on linux / gcc, don't remember version).

-*EDIT*-

I checked that code today, and here's new info:
First of all, the casting was used in a macro, and it expanded to

```
return (void)((void*)0);
```

within a function returning void.
The code compiles using gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 on (Red Hat 4.1.2-50).
So, is this statement equivalent to

```
return void;
```

which is equivalent to

```
return;
```

or is there something more to that?

Comment: I'm surprised that this even compiled at all - you shouldn't be able to compare values of void type.  Are you sure that this wasn't a cast to `void *`?

Comment: Absolutely sure, that's why I'm puzzled.

Comment: Yea that doesn't compile, at all

Comment: Can you please give the compiler that you used?  This doesn't compile on my version of `gcc`.

Comment: Yea, if this won't compile,
    auto ptr = (void)((void *)0);
Then you're missing something in your question

Comment: I get an error if I try that with gcc 4.3.2

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know, I've seen that on someone else's machine, some older gcc it was, but the person responsible for the code wasn't available. Maybe I'll be able to check it once more next week, but I'm pretty sure it was this way. Maybe I was doing something wrong or something else was redefined...

Comment: Probably a typo, missing a *.

Comment: It was impossible for it to be written that way, value of type 'void' is not contextually convertible to 'bool' or any type for that matter

Comment: I'll give it another check then. Thanks.

Comment: So if you're sure it wasn't `void*`, perhaps it could have been something that looked a lot like `void`? Maybe `vοіd`?

Comment: @g.tsh: So given the recent edit, it looks like the construct wasn't used in a comparison, but just used in the return for a `void` function. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the assembly for this case.

Having such a function:

```
void x() {
    return (void)(NULL);
}
```

Running preprocessor as: `gcc x.c -E -o x.E -Wall -Wextra` results in:

```
void x() {
    return (void)(((void *)0));
}
```

Which seems rather bizzare. Anyway, after compiling it with `gcc x.c -o x -Wall -Wextra`, the assembly is (from `objdump -d x`):

```
0804841d <x>:
 804841d:   55                      push   %ebp
 804841e:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048420:   90                      nop
 8048421:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 8048422:   c3                      ret
```

It's exactly the same as assembly for:

```
void x() {
    return;
}
```

So these two expressions are equivalent.

I am using `gcc version 4.8.2` (2013), for 64-bit linux, so it is not a bug of an old `gcc` version.

Adding `-pedantic` to `gcc`, however, makes it yield a warning:

> warning: ISO C forbids ‘return’ with expression, in function returning void [-Wpedantic]
>
> ```
> return (void)(NULL);
> ```

This happens for all of the dialects: `c89`, `c99`, `gnu89`, `gnu99`.

Answer (score 3):

It likely should be a cast to a *void pointer* which is the same as just "pointer" (i.e. a pointer to any type):

```
if (ptr != (void *)(NULL)) {
    ...
}
```

Although the cast is unnecessary:

```
if (ptr != NULL) {
    ...
}
```

Your code doesn't even compile on my system (Mac with GCC 4.2.1), the error message GCC is reporting is `void value not ignored as it ought to be`. That's expected and because `void` means *no value/type at all*, and you can't compare that to anything else.

Here's what the C99 standard is saying:

> **§6.3.2.2 void**
>
> 1 The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has type void) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be applied to such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its side effects.)
>
> **§6.5.9 Equality operators**
>
> Constraints
>
> 2 One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> - one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void; or
> - one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

§6.3.2.2 already forbids the usage of `void`, and the constraints in §6.5.9 would also be violated.

So if a compiler would allow `ptr != (void)(NULL)` then it would violate the C99 standard. It might simply be a bug or misfeature of an older GCC version.

I only found a draft for C89, and here the `void` section is almost the same as in C99. But the section about the equality operators leaves me scratching my head. It seems to allow comparing to `void`, but this might be a mistake in the draft or a wording problem:

> **§3.2.2.2 void**
>
> The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that
>   has type void) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or explicit
>   conversions (except to void ) shall not be applied to such an
>   expression.  If an expression of any other type occurs in a context
>   where a void expression is required, its value or designator is
>   discarded.  (A void expression is evaluated for its side effects.)
>
> **§3.3.9 Equality operators**
>
> …
>
> Constraints
>
> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> - one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a qualified or unqualified version of void ; or
> - one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

Comment: That doesn't explain how it compiled for the OP.

Comment: It might have been a bug/misfeature of an earlier GCC version, but even that seems dubious. The C99 standard §6.3.2.2 says: *The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has type void) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be applied to such an expression. If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its side effects.)* Also, the void type would violate the constraints for the equality operator in §6.5.9(2).